What is an overpass query to get OSM hiking trails in the US?
What is an overpass query to get OSM hiking trails in the US? I write "an overpass query" because I imagine that his can be done in multiple ways.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

this question may seem low-effort and overly generic, but actually I think it is a good beginner question and overpass query is quite specific. Maybe add a link to which type of query?

To solve your question:

web search "osm Overpass hiking"
End up on the osm overpass wiki
End up on hiking trails which says that a hiking trail is a relation, follow the link and find here that we want "route=hiking"
In the wizard enter route=hiking, copy query to clipboard and paste on GIS SE:

/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“route=hiking”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
nwr["route"="hiking"](51.94355060971912,5.648303031921388,51.96706261034769,5.693578720092774);
// print results
out geom;

Depending on the type of trails, you can add other queries and test in turbo wizard.

The request above returned the more significant trails and those with names that form the main trail network. It missed, however, lots of minor trails. I found the query below to be best. All the trails that were picked up by the nwr statement belonged to the way["highway"="path"] set.
`
[out:json];
(
nwr["route"="hiking"](43, -75.34, 44.9, -73.31);
way["highway"="path"](43, -75.34, 44.9, -73.31);
way["highway"="footway"](43, -75.34, 44.9, -73.31);
way["highway"="track"](43, -75.34, 44.9, -73.31);
);
out body;

;
out skel qt;
`


Below is the query I wrote to get hiking trails in a large bounding box containing the Adirondack Park in New York State, US. I checked trails in several regions of the US and found that the three highway values below captured everything except those that are actually roads, included forest service roads. It is possible that trails in other countries use other values too.
[out:json];
(
  way["highway"="path"](43, -75.34, 44.9, -73.31);
  way["highway"="footway"](43, -75.34, 44.9, -73.31);
  way["highway"="track"](43, -75.34, 44.9, -73.31);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;


This request is improved by incorporating the comment made by @Fee to include nwr["route"="hiking"](43, -75.34, 44.9, -73.31); Doing so adds the names to the main trails.
